# select all checkbox in datagrid header not working properly in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ey3.jpg)I am working on wpf mvvm datagrid and trying to bind the select all checkbox with the view model.  It is not giving me proper result. I am giving my code details here(The xaml code and the view model code)

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UsecaseListItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MyDataGrid"
          CanUserAddRows="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Width="50" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                        <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" Content="All" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UsecaseName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private bool _AllSelected;
    public bool AllSelected
    {
        get { return _AllSelected; }
        set
        {
            _AllSelected = value;
            foreach (var reportListItemModel in UsecaseListItems)
            {
                reportListItemModel.IsSelected = this._AllSelected;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");

        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<UseCase> _usecaseListItems = new ObservableCollection<UseCase>();
    public ObservableCollection<UseCase> UsecaseListItems
    {
        get { return _usecaseListItems; }
        set {
            _usecaseListItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UsecaseListItems");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to be wrong. Why do you want to bind it to a viewmodel? Why don't you try to bind the checkbox to the header checkbox isChecked?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I had...

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}
```

It didn't work, so I tried...

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}
```

... and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since allselected property in view model , you have to give ancestortype into window or user control instead of datagrid...

Comment: The main problem is When I am checking it half of the list (which is present at below part of the scroll bar ) is checked only and then again I scroll it up,the rest of the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: I have used updatesourcetrigger=true but still not working

Comment: check trigger event OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); instead of this give OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected");.. Also give ancestor type into window or usercontrol what ever it may be ...

Answer (score 0):

Check trigger event `OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");`. Instead of using this, give `OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected");`. Also give ancestor type into window or user-control what ever it may be ...